# Waking a locked phone up without the internet

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, offline, offlineapps

Edit: I've noticed that StackExchange has prefaced this question with *Android* but it applies for both iOS and Android.

We have a client side iOS/Android application that we expect to run (in remote Australia) with very limited internet connectivity. However, the application can expect to have very good connectivity to its local network, which is not on the net.

I've been looking into ways of waking a phone up with a notification of some sort whenever an event happens on the local server.

From what I've researched:

- Web push is no good as even the newer VAPID based protocol still wants to route some data through the browser vendor's notifications server.
- iOS Apple Notifications essentially have the same requirements as Web Push.
- A background task which periodically polls the server/wakes up a Websockets connection can work, but could end up with pretty long delays between polls.
- SMS is an option, as although 3G is limited, basic phone connectivity is sometimes available.

Are there any other ways of being able to wake up a locked mobile device with a server-sent event that I haven't listed? Given the operational situation having App Store compliance is not necessarily a requirement.

Cheers

Comment: You could look into sending intents via adb using the LAN

Comment: Are you asking for iOS or Android?  They're likely different answers, and half of what you're talking about makes no sense to an Android developer (browser vendor for push notification?  Push notifications have nothing to do with browsers).

Comment: @GabeSechan The Push i'm referring to is the [Web Push standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Push_API) that has some decent support these days. I'm not making any hard assumptions about _how_ the app would be packaged (native, Cordova, web page from internal server etc) - cross platform-edness would be a nice one to have though.

Comment: @GabeSechan The Push i'm referring to is the [Web Push standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Push_API) that has some decent support these days. I'm not making any hard assumptions about _how_ the app would be packaged (native, Cordova, web page from internal server etc) - cross platform-edness would be a nice one to have though.

Comment: You kind of are though- you're mentioning all web technologies, not normal mobile ones or native ones. MQTT would be the easiest way to solve your problem, but it's not a web technology- hooking it up to any of those would require effort

Comment: Management requires that iOS be supported - and iOS requires its Apple Push Notifications to go through their servers, so we either need internet (impossible in some areas - AU is a big place ;) ) or a more sensible way to do it.

Comment: does this help ? seems like what you are trying to achieve "Push notifications in a local network
" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22765019/push-notifications-in-a-local-network

Comment: @AngelKoh Its a very similar question - I didn't find that one before. At least in 2014 the answer still seemed to be same - in that at least some of the connection needs to be routed via an internet-accessible third party. I'm hoping that a few years of companies focusing more on offline-first apps might have added new possibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a fair bit of research, the answer (as of early 2018) is a pretty solid no, at least for a cross platform usecase.

iOS requires that an external notification that can wake the device come from a recognised internet-based source (APNS, and maybe in future the standardised VAPID based Push), from the mobile interface if available, or from the device itself which is limited by background execution restrictions.